# How do you resolve: GetEdmModel cannot be called more than once error?

Tags: odata

[image]

I have tried rebuilding the solution and deploying it. The deploy task finishes but I get the above error when the unicorn sync begins as the site cannot be accessed. I've searched online and cannot see any record of someone having a similar issue, can anyone offer any advice to troubleshoot this?

Comment: as per the screenshot, getEDMmodel called more than one time. could you find it where it is called? check the all route config

Answer (score 1):

I had this error after updating from Sitecore v9.1 to v10.3.1. This error appeared after publishing my solution to my new Sitecore v10.3.1 instance. I was able to resolve it by first looking through each of the assembly references found within the fresh v10.3.1 `Web.config` and updating my NuGet packages to match. This error is particular was resolved after updating the `Sitecore` Nuget packages to v10.3.1. After rebuilding and republishing the error was resolved.